# secure path for serviceAccountKey.json for a Firebase project in Google App Engine Node.js app

Tags: node.js, facebook, security, google-app-engine, firebase

I have a Firebase project that users share some content with consists of media and text. For Facebook to handle links properly shared content must have a pre-populated page (dynamically created on the server-side, not on the client with Firebase JS API).

So, I have decided to use Google App Engine (GAE) to serve these content as an URL like `somedomain.com/?content=hfe84gfjy45xs`

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

// Initialize the app with a null auth variable, limiting the server's access
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: null
});
```

Is it safe to put `path/to/serviceAccountKey.json` file in project folder?
Do i have to put the file to a Google Cloud Storage instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you ignored also the serviceAccountKey.json? If yes how you can use this on production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[express-firebase](https://github.com/antonybudianto/express-firebase) has a good example of accomplishing this.

1. Add your `serviceAccountKey.json` to your project BUT reference that file path in your `.gitignore` so it is not checked into source control.
2. Create a .env variable that is the path to your `serviceAccountKey.json` as so:

   ```
   FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH=./service-account-key.json
   ```

   See [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) for loading environments variables in JS apps.
3. From there, you can simply reference your service account file like so and pass it to the `cert` function:

   ```
   const serviceAccount = require(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH);

   admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
   ```

Comment: I must put into _.gitignore_  the file _serviceAccountKey.json_ or the _.env_?

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the these three values from the JSON file and put it in the `.env` file

```js
credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
}),
```